# MAMP Pro MySQL issue with changing database engine to InnoDB and migrating databases

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, myisam, mamp-pro

I have MAMP Pro on El Capitan running.  It has been fine up until now, but I've run into a problem.  I have a mixture of database, some using the MyISAM Engine and others using InnoDB.  I don't really know how that works.  I guess if some are InnoDB, the Engine is still MyISAM by default.  The issue is with databases that I have for Atlassians Confluence and JIRA.  In Confluence, all is good, but it says:

You should increase innodb_log_file_size to 256M

I tried playing around with the my.cnf, but ran into issues.  I restored things, and these are the relevant sections from the config.

```
[mysqld]
#port       = 9999
socket      = /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
key_buffer_size = 64M
max_allowed_packet = 512M

# table_cache only works for MySQL 5.5.x
#table_cache = 64

# If you are running MySQL 5.6.x, use table_open_cache.
#table_open_cache = 64

sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 32M

#Uncomment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
#innodb_data_home_dir = /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/
#innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
#innodb_log_group_home_dir = /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/
# You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
# of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
#innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M
#innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M
# Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
#innodb_log_file_size = 512M
#innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
#innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50
```

When I uncommented the InnoDB section the server crashes and the database got corrupted.

Just wondering how I can turn on InnoDB for MAMP, if that is recommended, and update my existing databases at the same time, the MyISAM ones and the InnoDB ones.

While I'm at it, I might want to upgrade MAMP to the newer MySQL version, maybe later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How much RAM do you have?

Keep `max_allowed_packet` under 2% of RAM.

Since you are using both MyISAM and InnoDB, set `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to about 1/3 of RAM unless; less if you have a tiny system.

Do not change `innodb_log_file_size` without further instructions.  That is, don't set it in my.cnf if it is not already set.

MyISAM and InnoDB can coexist.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I have 32 GB of RAM on a Mac system, so quite a bit. It is mostly an annoying error message or warning that I get from the Atlasssian apps running on tomcat on my server, although they are using the MAMP MySQL. I can try that. I am aware that you can change the log file, but you have to remove the old ones, be careful and have new ones created. I still don't understand why when I uncomment the other features that the server won't even start. Seems like it should run. Perhaps the 4.0 release of MAMP will fix that ?

Comment: So the innodb_buffer_pool_size can be as large as 10GB, Giga ?

Comment: I did make that change and it may help performance, but I still get this error from Confluence:

WarningInnoDB Log File Size
What does this check do?
Checks if the innodb_log_file_size variable in your MySQL database is appropriate.
Result
Your innodb_log_file_size of 5,242,880 is too small. You should increase innodb_log_file_size to 256M.
How can I resolve this?

Comment: I do see this on the confluence site.  [link][https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/database-setup-for-mysql-128747.html#DatabaseSetupForMySQL-Step3.ConfigureMySQLServer].  Can I make those adjustments after the DB has been created.  I have a backup that I can restore from, so if is doesn't work I have a fallback.

Comment: If you change `innodb_log_file_size` from what it was before the restart, it complains and refuses to start.  This is one of the few things that is dangerous to change.  Changing is a [multi-step process](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1261/how-to-safely-change-mysql-innodb-variable-innodb-log-file-size/4103#4103).

Comment: Yes, 10G should be fine.

Comment: If you had set the log_file_size _before_ bringing mysqld up the first time, all would have been well.  That link is a bit sloppy in that area.  Also, 256M vs 2G -- the difference won't matter much.

Comment: So, one last question.  Can I export my databases, back up any files, and do a clean install of MAMP with the InnoDB options enabled, or at least the innodb_log_file_size enabled.  Have MySQL start successfully and them import the databases into the new instance ?

Comment: Yes.  That should give you the upgrade, the changes to the settings, etc.  If MySQL is still in the same main version (eg, 5.6.xx to 5.6.yy), then there is very little chance of hiccups.  Use `mysqldump` (or competing products) for the dump.  If you have triggers or stored routines, be sure to grab them.  "Clean install" implies empty directory, so I don't think `mysql_upgrade` need be run.

Comment: Thank you, I think that may be the best solution.  I have Sequel Pro for Mac OS X.  I don't believe that I have any stored procedures.  I can just export the databases to an .sql file.  I also have some Atlasssian instances running, Confluence and JIRA, but I can back up those to an XML .zip and restore them to a new database.

MAMP is actually coming out with a 4.0 release of MAMP Pro soon, but I think what I have is fine.